# How to Use Stack's GHCI when in Haskell Interactive Mode

Tags: haskell-mode

I'm trying to maintain all of my package dependencies through Stack. However, when trying to use Haskell's Interactive Mode in Emacs, through [`haskell-mode`](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode), it won't find GHCI anymore, since it is only exposed through Stack now. How do I go around this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this line in your Emacs configuration in order to use Stack's GHCI:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'stack-ghci))
```

Then use the `haskell-session-change` command to change the buffer mode and enter interactive Haskell.

You can find more info in [this tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#non-interactive-commands).